# How to use setup FULL-TEXT Lucene SEARCH in H2 Database without errors?

Tags: lucene, indexing, seo, h2

I followed the H2 tutorial about setting the FTL using Lucene, however I'm experiencing unknown exceptions.

This is how I did it:
using SQuirrrel SQL Client I added the lucene-core-3.0.3.jar library in Additional classpath (otherwise it complains cannot import classes)
then I called this:

```
CREATE ALIAS IF NOT EXISTS FTL_INIT FOR "org.h2.fulltext.FullTextLucene.init";
CALL FTL_INIT();
```

Afterwards it the *.trace.db log said that the {db.name} exists but it's not a directory.

Answer (score 1):

I just fixed it, by renaming the database file to something else, then I made a directory named after the db.

Now running this:

```
CREATE ALIAS IF NOT EXISTS FTL_INIT FOR "org.h2.fulltext.FullTextLucene.init";
CALL FTL_INIT();
```

works.